# Django - Can't serving Static Files in production

Tags: python, django, static, django-staticfiles

(first, sorry for my bad english)
i'm having a problem serving the static files in a Digital Ocean server.

In develpment in my own computer all works perfect but i can't serve the statics in production, even the admin statics.

This is what i have in the settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)), 'static/')
```

Well, the command collect static work perfect and send the static files to my folder /home/username/project/static

if i check the folder i have all the static files but... the browser send the 404 error.

I try a lot of combinations in settings even hardcoded routes but always the same... The site give me this addres for static
http://myserverip:8000/static/admin/css/base.css But i can't see the files always 404

Thanks!!!

Comment: In django when you set DEBUG=False your static file must be handled by apache server or other

Comment: Thanks!!! i had in the production settings the DEBUG in False and i didn't finish the configuration of nginx, now i try with debug True and work perfect... now i can follow and set in false and config nginx.